# CardStyleInterpolator not being applied in Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a screen where I either want no animation or a slide-from-right animation depending on the value of the param I pass in the navigate function.

In the code below, the screen should slide in from the right when `withAnimation` is set to true, otherwise there is no animation. The `forNoAnimation` works correctly on both iOS and Android, but the sliding animation only works on iOS. It works on iOS. On Android it is seemingly doing some native animation still. Why is this not working properly?

```
import { CardStyleInterpolators, createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const MainAppStack = createStackNavigator();
const MainAppStackNavigator = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <MainAppStack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="OtherScreen"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                gestureEnabled: false
            }}>
        <MainAppStack.Screen
            name="DetailsScreen"
            component={DetailsScreen}
            options={({ route: { params } }) => ({
                cardStyleInterpolator: params?.withAnimation
                    ? CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
                    : CardStyleInterpolators.forNoAnimation
            })}
        />
        </MainAppStack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Comment: Are you using `@react-navigation/stack` to create the stack ?

Comment: @AakashRathee yup I am. will update my post to show it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did

```
import { createStackNavigator, CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

```
          <Stack.Screen 
                name='Article' 
                component={Article}
                options={{ 
                    title: '',
                    headerTransparent: true,
                    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS,
                    headerLeft: () => <View />,
                    headerRight: () => <RightHeaderArticle />,
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
                    },
                }}
            />
```